# Dynamically populate multiple (more than one) dropdown choices/options (Flask, python, Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

how do I dynamically update multiple dropdown menus based upon the previous selection?  (This code only has three dropdowns but eventually I will add 2 more).

Problem: the second dropdown (category_2) correctly reads the value of the first and only passes a list (via json) of the values that are not equal to the first.  BUT, I can't figure out how to pass both the category_1 and category_2 values to the third dropdown.

(Note, I can include the template page and form code if that helps.  Right now, I was hoping someone could help diagnose the proper way to send two variables or a json string).

Here is my code:
**App.py**
    import json
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, make_response
    from form import TestForm
    import json

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "my precious"

extra = ['Product_Type','Geography','Third']

@app.route("/category", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    """
    Render form and handle form submission
    """
    form = TestForm(request.form)
    form.category_1.choices = [('', 'Select a Category')] + [(x) for x in enumerate(extra,1)]
    chosen_category_1 = None
    chosen_category_2 = None
    chosen_category_3 = None
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

@app.route("/category/<int:category_1_id>/", methods=["POST"])
def get_request(category_1_id):
    data = [(x) for x in enumerate(extra,1)
        if x[0] != category_1_id]
    response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

  // test to ensure jQuery is working
  console.log("whee!")

  // disable refresh button
  $("#refresh-btn").prop("disabled", true)


  $("#category_1_select").change(function() {

    // grab value
    var category_1_id = $("#category_1_select").val();
    var category_2_id = $("#category_2_select").val();


    // send value via GET to URL /<category_id>
    var get_request = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/category/' + category_1_id + '/',
    });

    // handle response
    get_request.done(function(data){

      // data
      console.log(data)

      // add values to list 
      var option_list = [["", "Select another category"]].concat(data);
      $("#employee_select").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < option_list.length; i++) {
          $("#employee_select").append(
            $("<option></option>").attr("value", option_list[i][0]).text(option_list[i][1]));
        }
      // show model list
      $("#employee_select").show();
    });
  });

$("#employee_select").change(function() {

    // grab value
    var category_1_id = $("#category_1_select").val();
    var category_2_id = $("#category_2_select").val();

    // send value via GET to URL /<category_id>
    var get_request = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'JSON.stringify([category_1_id, category_2_id])',
      url: '/category/' + category_1_id + '/',
    });

    // handle response
    get_request.done(function(data){

      // data
      console.log(data)

      // add values to list 
      var option_list = [["", "Select another category"]].concat(data);
      $("#category_3_select").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < option_list.length; i++) {
          $("#category_3_select").append(
            $("<option></option>").attr("value", option_list[i][0]).text(option_list[i][1]));
        }
      // show model list
      $("#category_3_select").show();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but here is how I have solved it.

In #employee_select section, I passed the category_2_select variable and routed to flask. (Note the change to url):

JS addition:

```
$("#employee_select").change(function() {
// grab value
var category_1_id = $("#category_1_select").val();
var category_2_id = $("#category_2_select").val();

// send value via GET to URL /<category_id>
var get_request = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'JSON.stringify([category_1_id, category_2_id])',
  url: '/category/' + category_1_id + '/'+ category_2_id + '/',
});
```

Then on my app.py, I added the following:

```
@app.route("/category/<int:category_1_id>/<int:category_2_id>/", methods=["POST"])
def get_request(category_1_id,category_2_id):
    data = [(x) for x in enumerate(extra,1)
        if x[0] != category_1_id and x[0] != category_2_id]
    response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return response
```

Note, the category_2_id MUST have a value.  (the flask route will not read a 'null' value).